# get text background of <span> within <pre> block to extend to full line width (set by container)

Tags: html, css

I use `<span>` tags to highlight some parts of pre-formatted text by setting it's background colour. If the `<span>` contains a line-break, the selected background colour stops at the last character before the line-break, and continues on the next line. Instead I would like the background colour to extend to the full width of the container. How could I achieve this (preferably using CSS only)?

Example:

```html
<pre style="width: 20ex;background:gray">
A B <span style="background:red">C
D E</span> F G H
</pre>
```

Here, the red background behind `C` should extend all the way to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positioned pseudo-element could do that.

```css
pre {
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: hidden; /* required */
}

pre span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

pre span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 1.2em; /* whatever your line-height is */
  width: 50em; /* some arbitrary large width*/
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<pre style="width: 20ex;background:gray">
A B <span style="background:red">C
D E</span> F G H
</pre>
```

Comment: Looks promising! However, when I run your code snippet in my firefox, the C gets lost. I assume the z-index should have taken care of that?

Comment: However, changing the CSS to `left: 100%` (was `left: 0`) does the job in my case, I took the liberty to edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like this

```html
<pre style="width: 20ex;background:gray">
A B <span style="background:red;display: block;">C
D E</span> F G H
</pre>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I'm looking for: It splits the lines around the span, which does not conform to the pre-formatted text any more.